# Reference a dll built with F# 3.x (Visual Studio 2012/13) from an F# 2.0 (Visual Studio 2010) project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, f#, f#-3.0

Is it possible to reference a dll built with F# 3.x (Visual Studio 2012/13) from an F# 2.0 (Visual Studio 2010) project? Or indeed load a dll built with F# 3.x from the version of FSI that ships with F# 2.0 / Visual Studio 2010?

My impression is that F# 3.x does not have any backwards compatibility with F# 2.0. Is this understanding correct? For example, is it true that FSharp.Core F# 2.0 can't target FSharp.Core 4.0.3.x and F# 3.0 can't target FSharp.Core 4.0.0.0?